# Converting HQL 'in' restriction to Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, criteria

I have a query like this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from table1 c where c.colummewhatever =:value and (select p.colummewhatever from table2 p where c.fkidcolumme=p.idcolumme) in (:listPColummewhatever) ");
```

Is there a way to translate the `in` restriction into `Criteria`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this query could be rewritten using a simple join:

```
from Table1 c inner join c.table2 p
where c.colummewhatever =:value 
and p.colummewhatever in (:listPColummewhatever)
```

Translating this HQL query in Criteria is now much easier.

This of course supposes that you have an association between Table1 and Table2, but you should have one.

Comment: well tks!....just one tiny problem I didn't know how to translate joins into Criteria....meanwhile I've found DetachedCriteria :)

Comment: You don't need DetachedCriteria to create joins. Why don't you read the reference documentation, where it's all explained? http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-associations

Answer (score 0):

Using the Criteria API should be somethin like this...

```
DetachedCriteria dc = new DetachedCriteria.forClass(Table1.class,"c");
dc.createAlias("table2","p")
dc.add(Restrictions.in("p.colFoo",yourListFoo);
dc.add(Restrictions.eq("c.col",value);

List<Table1> = dc.getExecutableCriteria(session).list();
```